# Does the ASUS P7P55D Motherboard support the 4th generation Intel Core i5 processor?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a PC I built based on the ASUS P7P55D motherboard.  Currently it has an Intel Core i5-750 LGA1156 processor in it, a 3rd generation processor.  I just found out that to run the Intel RealSense camera I need to a 4th generation Core i5.  Will my ASUS motherboard support the new 4th generation processors?

Comment: No;  Its not compatible. The list of compatible processors are on the product specification page for your motherboard.  Your motherboard doesn't even support Ivybridge processors let alone Haswell processors.